# Loading Maven downloaded jars into eclipse causes the codes unresponsive

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, jar

I have used maven to download the necessary jars and then I run *maven eclipse:eclipse* command to load that jars into eclipse. The jars are successfully loaded but the problem is that without the necessary packages being imported the classes are not marked with any error and also I can't run the program.

Here see the screenshot to better understand the problem.

[image: no errors are being marked, no packages are imported]

Comment: which Eclipse version do you use? mvn eclipse:eclipse is deprecated. You should use the M2E integration in Eclipse and import your project correctly.

Comment: I feel like a screenshot of your "Problems" view would be helpful.  Seems like the build path isn't complete because if it was building, errors would show in the Java file, according to default behavior.  You may need to Right click on the project and refresh.  I still use mvn eclipse:eclipse.

Comment: @khmarbaise I use Eclipse Helios. I import my project again but the problem remain same. So i add jars manually and the problem is solved.

Comment: Before you import the project you need to delete `.project`, `.classpath` and `.settings` from the projects folders. If you don't the will be reused instead newly created. Apart from that I can recommend to use a new Eclipse version or update the M2E plugin in your Eclipse...